# Match a string in a csv using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, csv, el

I am new to regular expression. I have a requirement to match a string in a csv string. I can do this using a regular substring/startswith/endswith EL expression, however i want to try it using regex. Any help on this will be highly appreciable.

My CSV Pattern named *myCSV*: PAT,BAT,924,EH,23,5A,G12
It can have a csv with any alphanumeric characters.
My String named *myString* would be any of PAT or BAT or 924 etc 
I want to check if *myString* exist in the *myCSV*

I am trying the following code and it didn't work. :(

```
<c:set var="myRegEx" value="([,]?)+${myString}+([,]?)" scope="page"/>
<c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(myCSV , myRegEx)}">
// do stuffs
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

The '+' symbol in a regular expression is a quantifier, it stands for "one or more" so you are using it wrong you don't need to concatenate if that is what you are trying. You also need to use the method [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks, I tried using ([,]?)${myString}([,]?) i.e., without '+' and it didn't work.

Comment: @user2187477 Here ${myCSV == myRegEx} you are only testing if the objects are the same, not using the regex.